# can't open fossil repo over web

Tags: apache, fossil

I've been strugling for a couple of days with this problem, but can't seem to fix it, I think I'm almost there.... but... not quite :(

This is where I am at.

I'm on a headless debian server, running virtualmin / webmin for creating my domains / users etc. I don't know if this will mess things up, but I'm happy to modify the config files manually (via webmin or via ssh/vim).

I am attempting to run fossil as a cgi service over apache.

its an internal site, named as homeserver.net I can reach the default pages just fine, and add in and create links etc as I want to.

Please note that the solution to my problem is at the end of the question.

so the files are located on disk at, which tallys up with my apache document root

```
/home/homeserver/www
```

I would like to run fossil to have both the internal site, and later on and dev work that I practice on in separate files. So I created a new directory for these repositories.

```
/home/homeserver/repos/web/site.fossil
/home/homeserver/repos/dev/ [no repository yet!]
```

reading the instructions on the [fossil page](https://www.fossil-scm.org/fossil/doc/trunk/www/server.wiki) I have inserted a short cgi file called 'fos_repo.cgi' that reads as.

```
#!/usr/bin/fossil
directory: /home/homeserver/repos
notfound: http://www.homeserver.net/site404.htm
```

when I open the link to

```
www.homeserver.net/cgi-bin/fos_repo.cgi
```

I get redirected to the 404 page that I have written. So the script is clearly being read and working.

From reading the fossil pages I understand that I should be able to use the following link to open/access the repo.

```
www.homeserver.net/cgi-bin/repos/web/site
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working...

so far I have tried the following.

I opened the repository from the cli, and had the server run in the background

fossil server site.fossil &

I though maybee the file should have been inside the main repo directory, not inside a sub directory, so I moved it... it now lives in

```
/home/homeserver/repos/site.fossil
```

I tried creating an alias to the file in apache

```
Alias /home/homeserver/repos/web/site.fossil /home/homeserver/www/repos
```

When I browse to

```
 www.homeserver.net/repos/site
```

I get nothing, but going to

```
www.homeserver.net/repos/site.fossil
```

will attempt to downloaded the file (which is a binary)

so I think I'm getting somewhere, but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

I've used fossil before, but I ran it as a local server, and started it up as and when I needed it.
I'm running it like this so as I can eventually push the site out to a live VPS (maybe even finish up hosting the fossil site on the VPS also).

ps I really liked fossil when I used it before, and loved the whole integrated wiki and bug tracker, and the fact I could simply copy the file to my external drive to do a backup. Personally don't really want to change to something else, but if I have to....

thanks in advance.

David

Edit: trying other options.

So I thought I would try the single repository method shown on the fossil page, so adjusted my cgi script accordingly.

Now when I navitage to : www.homeserver.net/cgi-bin/fos_repo.cgi I get the following message returned

```
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: cannot open file at line 30276 of [f5b5a13f73]
SQLITE_CANTOPEN: os_unix.c:30276: (21) open(/home/homeserver/repos)
```

however if I ssh to the server an start it manually with

```
fossil server site.fossil
```

I can get to the server with www.homeserver.net:8081

So I either have a problem with my SQLite usage in apache or something else wrong. Plesse help

**Solution**

So for reasons of simplicity I've decided that using a single cgi file for each repo is what I am going to go with.

My initial directory structure was as follows:

```
/home/homeserver/www
/home/homeserver/www/repos
/home/homeserver/www/repos/web # for web site development
/home/homeserver/www/repos/dev # for other development
```

I think part of my problem was that I was hoping that having the *directory*: pont to my *repos*/ location fossil would find the *site.fossil* file (located in *repos/web*) and the *dev.fossil* file (located in *repos/deb*).

Obviously this didn't work.
The reason I wanted it too look like this was for separation of the information on my system.

For some reason I had decided that pointing fossil as *repos/* would give me a nice fossil style front page and links to my repositories automatically. However After having used the *directory:* version and getting the following error message

```
Unable to find or open the project repository
```

I realised that I was still going to need to write my front page to the repositories, and that my expectation was a little too much.

So I've decided to run with a single cgi file pointing to each repo that i need to make.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
www.homeserver.net/cgi-bin/repos/web/site
```

try

```
www.homeserver.net/cgi-bin/repos.cgi/index
```

Reading your ( very long ) question again, I suggest trying

```
www.homeserver.net/cgi-bin/fos_repos.cgi/index
```

Comment: That seemed like a really logically good idea... but it didn't work. I also tried all the possible combinations. Added in a note to the original to mention that I am running the server with Virtualmin/Webmin, if that has messed things up somewhere ? David

Comment: The only thing that Virtualmin would cause to maybe be done differently is that it defaults to running all web applications as the owner of the domain using suexec. So, file permissions have to be correct in a Virtualmin system (the most common error people make there is to set them to 777; suexec will not execute if the app is world or group writeable). So, check to be sure your app has owner/group set to homeserver, and that the app is not world/group writeable.

Comment: @swelljoe I can confirm that the user and group for the directory is 'homeserver', and the permissions on all folders / files is 755. although I had dropped onto this problem, and eventually found this as the problem when searching through the apache error log for the server. ravenspoint I tried your /index and I get the same sqlite error message.

Comment: I'm getting somewhere. I've just tried again, using chuser homeserver:homeserver -R-v and then chmodiing all the files and I can now get the repository to work as a 'standalone' repository. Now it is just a question of getting it to work as a 'directory'.

Comment: @ravenspoint I've edited your comment to outline my solution, although it isn't exactly as I had wanted.

Comment: @ravenspoint Ok I've changed my mind. it was a very long edit. My solution is to use a separate cgi file for each repository that I am wanting to create. For some reason I though the directory form would allow me to have a 'fossil' page that linked to all the found repositories, and be able to create new ones etc etc. Marking thread solved.